# ZF2 Nested Collection element has no value

Tags: php, forms, collections, zend-framework2

I have created a form with nested Collection Customer(Form) -> Categories(Collection/Fieldset) -> Tags(Collection/Fieldset).

It's: 
One(Customer) -> Many(Categories)
One(Catogrie) -> Many(Tags)

After bind the customer to the Form it looks like everything is working fine. The Hydrator get the object and the elements where created in Tags.

But in the View the Tag-Elements have no value...

I have checked the Hydrator for typos but everything is fine I copy/paste the index to make sure. When i var_dump the Tags-Collection the objects with value are binded.

I really dont know where the error is, thats why i dont enter some code here I think it would be to much. When you have an idea I can show you the code where you guess the error can be.

Greetings.

Tiega.

EDIT:

Okay I will try to do my best to give you readable code :)

```
class KontakteController extends AbstractActionController {



public function getKontaktAction()
{
    $formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
    $kontaktForm = $formManager->get('KontakteManager\Form\KontakteForm');

    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    $kontakt = $this->getKontakte()->getKontakt($id);
    if (!$id || !$kontakt) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('kontakte', array(
            'action' => 'addKontakt'
        ));
    }

    $kontakt->initFirmaKommunikation($this->getKommunikation());
    $kontakt->initAdressen($this->getAdressen());
    $kontakt->initAnsprechpartner($this->getKontakte());
    $kontakt->initBankverbindungen($this->getBankverbindung());
    $kontakt->initFirmaKategorien($this->getKontakteKategorie());
    $kontakt->initPersonKategoiern($this->getKontakteKategorie());
    $kontaktForm->bind($kontakt);

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'kontaktForm'       => $kontaktForm,
        'geloescht'         => $kontakt->geloescht,
        'tags'              => $this->ladeTags(),
    ));
}
```

CustomerFieldset:

```
class KontakteForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('kontakt');

    $this->setHydrator(new KontaktHydrator())
        ->setObject(new Kontakt());

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'firmaKategorien',
        'options' => array(
            'count' => 0,
            'allow_add'      => true,
            'allow_remove'   => true,
            'should_create_template' => false,
            'target_element' => array(
                'type' => 'KontakteManager\Form\KontaktKategorieFieldset'
            )
        )
    ));

}

/**
 * @return array
\*/
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array();
}
```

The CategorieFieldset:

```
class KontaktKategorieFieldset extends Fieldset {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('kontakteKategorie');
    $this->setHydrator(new KontaktKategorieFieldsetHydrator())
        ->setObject(new KontaktKategorie());

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'bezeichnung',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
        'options'   => array(
            'label' => 'Kategorie',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'tags',
        'options' => array(
            'count' => 0,
            'allow_add'      => true,
            'allow_remove'   => true,
            'should_create_template' => false,
            'target_element' => array(
                'type' => 'KontakteManager\Form\TagFieldset'
            )
        )
    ));

}
```

And the TagFielset:

```
class TagFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('Tag');
    $this->setHydrator(new TagHydrator())
        ->setObject(new Tag());

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'mehrsprachig',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
        'options'   => array(
            'label' => 'Mehrsprachig',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'kategorieID',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'bezeichnung',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class'     => 'form-control',
            'readonly'  => 'readonly',
        ),
        'options'   => array(
            'label' => 'Bezeichnung',
        ),
    ));
}


/**
 * @return array
\*/
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array();
}
```

And the View code how i try to display the collections

```
                        <h5 class="text-primary"><strong>Kategorien</strong></h5>
                    <hr>
                    <?php foreach($kontaktForm->get('firmaKategorien') as $element): ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <?php echo $this->formElement($element->get('bezeichnung')); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <?php foreach($element->get('tags') as $tag): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->formElement($tag->get('bezeichnung')); ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and here an example result:

```
<h5 class="text-primary"><strong>Kategorien</strong></h5>
<hr>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" name="firmaKategorien[0][bezeichnung]" class="form-control" value="Druckerei">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" name="firmaKategorien[0][tags][0][bezeichnung]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="">
        <input type="text" name="firmaKategorien[0][tags][1][bezeichnung]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some code will be useful :)

Comment: what about the controller?

Comment: done :) i've added an example result too. I hope this will help you to help me :D

Answer (score 0):

See if this will make any changes

```
$kontaktForm->bind($kontakt);
//Add this line
$kontaktForm->setData((Array)$kontakt);
```

Please post back the error you get

Comment: are you sure that $kontakt contains data?

Comment: yes, the rest of the form contains the correct data, just the tags values are missing. Just check the example result there you can see that there are datas.... And like i sad when i var_dump the tagsCollection i can see that the right objects are binded

Comment: I guess i found where the error where produced. I go deeper and checked how die Fieldset->extract() works. While i was following the process i saw that 'tags' will be extract but the returned array will not be saved in 'firmaKategorie'...

But i dont know why....

Comment: Ok so, it have value empty, because is not saving.

Comment: you know why its not saving?

Comment: can you var_dump this: $kontakt = $this->getKontakte()->getKontakt($id); if this is the picture you post already, your model is wrong.

Comment: Sry i was on vacation. I can but the result is quite long, there are lots of data inside^^

The picture only shows the 'firmaKategorie' and 'tags' from the $kontakt. i did the var_dump in the pic direct in the fieldset->extract() (if $name == 'tags' || $name == 'firmaKategorie') :)

Comment: just incase this helps, im having exactly the same problem while using Doctrine. Any more clues? I have spent the last 3 hours getting to where youre at and then get lost in the huge data arrays

Comment: if youre using composer run update, i just did and it solved it for me. not sure what was causing the issue unfortunately

Comment: @Tiega more than welcome :) glad it solved it for you too, that was becoming a real nightmare! I had posted that as an answer but it was deleted for apparently not providing a proper answer to the question